Laravel Broadcasting not firing on the Job Queue
I am creating a AI ChatBot. The message is entered on the frontend (Livewire) and then stored in the database. A model "created" listener then pushes a job onto the queue which asks the AI (LLM) the prompt and the answer is then updated on the model (on the queue). There is then an "updated" listener, which fires a broadcasting event.
On the front end the Livewire component is listening via Laravel Echo for the updated event, and the chat response is shown to the user.
The problem I have is that the broadcasting event works, but not on the queue. I have tested it via a Console Command and it updates the chat, but when the job is processed on the queue, no update occurs.
I have checked the Herd logs, and again, I can see the event broadcasting when I manually trigger with the Console Command, but no event is broadcasted when the job is processed on the queue.
So:

The job to get the llm response is always successfully processed on the queue when the model is created
The LlmMessage model is always updated successfully by this job, and the response is stored
The LlmMessageUpdated event is broadcasted and the Livewire Component updated when a manual update is triggered
The LlmMessageUpdated event is not broadcasted and the Livewire Component is not updated when the job updates the model

Where am I going wrong?
Code:
LlmMessage Model

<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Events\LlmMessageUpdated;
use App\Jobs\GetLlmMessageResponse;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Pgvector\Laravel\Vector;

/**
 * @property int $user_id
 * @property string $prompt
 * @property string $response
 */
class LlmMessage extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'llm';

    protected $fillable = [
        "user_id",
        "prompt",
        "response"
    ];

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function getFormattedPrompt()
    {
        $pd = new \Parsedown();
        $pd->setSafeMode(true);
        return $pd->text($this->prompt);
    }

    public function getFormattedResponse()
    {
        $pd = new \Parsedown();
        $pd->setSafeMode(true);
        return $pd->text($this->response);
    }

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::created(function (LlmMessage $message) {
            GetLlmMessageResponse::dispatch($message);
        });

        static::updated(function (LlmMessage $message) {
            LlmMessageUpdated::dispatch($message->id, $message->user_id);
        });
    }
}


Event To Broadcast

<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class LlmMessageUpdated implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     */
    public function __construct(public int $id, public int $user_id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array<int, \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel>
     */
    public function broadcastOn(): array
    {
        return [
            'llm-thread-' . $this->user_id
        ];
    }
}

Frontend Livewire Component

<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use App\Models\LlmMessage;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Livewire\Attributes\Validate;
use Livewire\Component;

class LlmChat extends Component
{
    #[Validate('required|max:1000')]
    public string $body = '';

    public Collection $chatMessages;

    public function getChatMessages()
    {
        return $this->chatMessages;
    }

    public function getListeners()
    {
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;

        return [
            "echo:llm-thread-{$user_id},LlmMessageUpdated" => 'onMessageUpdated',
        ];
    }

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->chatMessages = LlmMessage::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
            ->take(20)
            ->get();
    }

    public function send()
    {
        $this->validate();

        $this->chatMessages->push(LlmMessage::create([
            "user_id" => auth()->user()->id,
            "prompt" => $this->body
        ]));

        $this->body = '';
    }

    public function onMessageUpdated($data)
    {
        $index = $this->chatMessages->search(fn($chatMessage) => $chatMessage->id === $data['id']);
        $this->chatMessages[$index] = LlmMessage::findOrFail($data['id']);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.llm-chat')
            ->layout('livewire.layout.chat-app');
    }
}

Laravel Herd Reverb Logs showing event firing when manually triggered:


When developing, I had Laravel Horizon running in the background as the queue driver. It hadn't been restarted and was running the old instance of Laravel which didn't have the new event/broadcasting code. So when I restarted it, it ran the event perfectly.
